# Циклический сдвиг массива вниз

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть двухмерный массив Arr, который заполняется случайными числами, размер массива определяет пользователь.

Необходимо:

> Осуществить циклический сдвиг элементов прямоугольной матрицы на один элемент вниз

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой алгоритм действий необходимо реализовать, чтобы осуществить сдвиг? Уже многое перепробовал, никак не получается.

```
using System;
class Array {
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("введите количество строк массива: ");
    int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("введите количество столбцов массива: ");
    int M = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("создание массива: ");
    int[,] Arr = new int[N,M];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        string s = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            Arr[i,j] = rand.Next(-50,50);
            s = s + string.Join("{0,7}", Arr[i,j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Была попытка сдвинуть массив следующим образом:

```
int newz = 0, newi = 0;     
Console.WriteLine("Сдвиг вниз:");
int newarr = N - 1 % N;
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
   {
     newj= j;
     newi = (i + newarr) % N;
     Console.Write("\t" + Arr[newi, newj]);
   }
 Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Однако в таком случае он как-будто бы просто копирует последнюю строку массива и переставляет её вверх, а остальные элементы так и остаются на своих местах.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121135/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще задача простая, запомнить последнюю строчку в одномерный массив длиной в количество колонок. Затем переместить каждый элемент массива на одну строчку вниз, затем записать в первую строку ранее запоменнное содержимое последней строки.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("введите количество строк массива: ");
        int rows = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("введите количество столбцов массива: ");
        int columns = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("создание массива: ");
        int[,] array = CreateArray(rows, columns);
        PrintArray(array);
        Console.WriteLine("сдвиг массива: ");
        ShiftArrayDown(array);
        PrintArray(array);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int[,] CreateArray(int rows, int columns)
    {
        int[,] array = new int[rows, columns];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
            {
                array[i, j] = rand.Next(-50, 50);
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static void PrintArray(int[,] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(4));
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    private static void ShiftArrayDown(int[,] array)
    {
        int[] lastRow = new int[array.GetLength(1)];
        int lastRowIndex = array.GetLength(0) - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            lastRow[j] = array[lastRowIndex, j];

        for (int i = lastRowIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
                array[i + 1, j] = array[i, j];

        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            array[0, j] = lastRow[j];
    }
}
```

В качестве домашнего задания - разберитесь, как это работает.

```
введите количество строк массива: 4
введите количество столбцов массива: 5
создание массива:
  3  15 -14 -26 -46
 25  13  19 -37 -33
-13 -29 -30  32   1
 11 -19 -50  46  13
сдвиг массива:
 11 -19 -50  46  13
  3  15 -14 -26 -46
 25  13  19 -37 -33
-13 -29 -30  32   1
```

---

Кстати, для более опытных разработчиков есть способ попроще, который "вот так вот в лоб", я думал по началу, не будет работать, но работает. Если кто знает, почему оно работает (ведь данные по идее должны затираться при копировании начиная со второй строки), расскажите, мне интересно. Получается, память копируется с использованием какого-то буфера, то есть блок памяти вычитывается в буфер, а потом записывается. Где бы узнать, каков размер этого буфера, и как вообще точно оно работает?

```cs
private static void ShiftArrayDown(int[,] array)
{
    int[] lastRow = new int[array.GetLength(1)];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, (array.GetLength(0) - 1) * array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int), lastRow, 0, array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int));
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int), (array.GetLength(0) - 1) * array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int));
    Buffer.BlockCopy(lastRow, 0, array, 0, array.GetLength(1) * sizeof(int));
}
```

**UPD:** [Ответ найден](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d64c11eabf313cbd52c2f83f89d5a63ad91ddca2/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Buffer.cs#L147-L150) - `Buffer.BlockCopy` безопасен для перекрывающих друг друга областей памяти. Если кратко, то есть [2 функции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415926/12888024) - `memcpy` и `memmove`, первая быстрее, но повредит данные при таком копировании, вторая медленнее, но безопасно переносит участок памяти даже если целевой учаток перекрывается с исходным. `Buffer.BlockCopy` сверяет исходный адрес и целевой адрес и выполняет ту функцию, которая безопасно подходит для данного конкретного случая. То есть решение выше правильное и безопасное.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что сдвигать нужно строку? Судя по последнему комментарию автора, ему не строки сдвигать нужно.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков "сдвиг вниз" и "сдвиг на 1 элемент" - 2 большие разницы, обе имеющие вполне однозначное для меня значение. Ну посмотрим, удалить ответ не долго.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков ну заодно и `Buffer.BlockCopy` я разобрался, так что этот ответ даже для меня был полезен. :)