# Смещение строк в двумерном массиве

Tags: c#

Всем привет. В данный момент встала задача написать скрипт для смещения значений в многомерном массиве. Написал такой код, он справляется со своей задачей пока значения и сдвиг массива не становится слишком огромным что может выйти за пределы массива. Как можно это исправить, не могу придумать формулу для такого случая.

Всем привет. Появилась задача для написания метода который будет принимать в себя многомерный (а именно двумерный массив), а также **num** - который будет указывать число раз сколько нужно сместить строки в массиве вниз или вверх в зависимости от значения. И возвращать массив.

```
private bool[,] TestVertical(bool[,] array, int num)
{
    //смещение массива по GetLength(0)

    //num - значение отвечающее за смещение массива

    bool[,] rArray = new bool[array.GetLength(0), array.GetLength(1)];

    int length0 = array.GetLength(0);
    int length1 = array.GetLength(1);

    for (int a = 0; a < length0; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < length1; b++)
        {
            int c;
            if(a + num >= length0)
            {
                c = (length0 - (a + num)) * -1;
                rArray[a, b] = array[c, b];
            }
            else
            {
                c = a + num;
                rArray[a, b] = array[c, b];
            }
        }
    }

    return rArray;
}
```

Вот хотелось бы на выходе иметь похожий результат, на данном примере смещение массива на единицу

[image: Ожидаю получить похожий результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно есть вариант решения еще проще, но и этот вроде не сложный

```cs
private static bool[,] RotateArray(bool[,] array, int shift)
{
    int height = array.GetLength(0);
    int width = array.GetLength(1);

    // отрезаем полные периоды от смещения
    shift %= height;
    // если отрицательное смещение, то преобразуем отрицательное смещение в положительное
    shift = shift < 0 ? height - Math.Abs(shift) : shift;

    bool[,] result = new bool[height, width];

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            result[(i + shift) % height, j] = array[i, j];

    return result;
}
```

Проверка

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool[,] array = new bool[,]
    {
        { true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true  },
        { false, false, false, false, false, false },
        { true,  false, true,  false, false, true  },
        { true,  false, true,  false, false, true  }
    };

    PrintArray(array);
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', array.GetLength(1) * 2));
    array = RotateArray(array, 1);
    PrintArray(array);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void PrintArray(bool[,] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            Console.Write((array[i, j] ? 1 : 0) + " ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1
------------
1 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1
```

---

Еще один вариант решения для продвинутых разработчиков

```cs
private static bool[,] RotateArrayFast(bool[,] array, int shift)
{
    int height = array.GetLength(0);
    int width = array.GetLength(1);

    shift %= height;
    shift = shift < 0 ? height - Math.Abs(shift) : shift;
            
    bool[,] result = new bool[height, width];

    int offset = shift * width;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, result, offset, array.Length - offset);
    if (offset != 0)
        Buffer.BlockCopy(array, array.Length - offset, result, 0, offset);

    return result;
}
```

Есть [еще один ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1258818/373567) на похожий вопрос.

Comment: К варианту для продвинутых разработчиков недостаточно продвинутых комментариев =)

Comment: @Blackmeser `bool` = 1 байт. Это единственный комментарий, который здесь имеет значение.